# How to add multiple products at once in the shop cart?

Tags: grouped-products

I have made a new Magento shopping store .I want my customers can to add multiple products at once in the shop cart, is this possible ?
can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add products to cart programmatically:

```
/** @var Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart */
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$productIds = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->load($productId);
    $cart->addProduct($product);
    $cart->save();
}
```

and build the functionality where you need it. Or buy a module like
[this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-multiple-products-to-cart.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
class BTS_AddMultipleProducts_AddController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function indexAction() {

    $products = explode(',', $this->getRequest()->getParam('products'));
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); 
    $cart->init(); /* @var $pModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */ 
    foreach ($products as $product_id) { 
        if ($product_id == '') { continue; } 
        $pModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
        if ($pModel->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {
         try {
            $cart->addProduct($pModel, array('qty' => '1')); 
          } catch (Exception $e) {
                continue; 
          } 
        } 
    } 
    $cart->save(); 
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        exit('1'); 
    } $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); 
}
```

}

You can follow this link

http://www.danneh.org/2011/09/adding-multiple-products-cart-simultaneously-magento-part-2/

Its also help you.

Comment: It would be great if you could rephrase the most important parts and copy them over there, so your answer is still helpful when the link is dead.